# How can I get water to fill a volume in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm a librarian running a Minecraft program where players will construct a city in a glass dome underwater.  At the end of the program I want to flood the dome so they can see their city submerged.  I can't quite get water to flood the area without going through and breaking each piece of glass.  The best I've done is construct a flood gate with pistons on the top and sides of the dome to allow water to enter, but this does not fill the volume and stops after a block or two.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  Is there a mod?  We run version 1.7.10.

Comment: Why are you in 1.7.10? That's almost 5 years old.

Comment: Why can't they just build underwater? Survival or Creative? And do you want to fill the insides of the buildings, too? If not, what should define "inside" and "outside"? Does it have to be source water or can it be water flowing down? If it can be flowing water, you can just fill an area above it.

Comment: We use 1.7.10 because we use Minecraft.edu, not to be confused with Educational Edition.  That version never updated beyond 1.7.10.  The players that come to the program tend to be very young (around 6 or so) and not very focused or adept at playing yet, so I need to design things to be as accessible as possible, and that means clearing the chamber of water first.

Comment: Survival or Creative? And do you want to fill the insides of the buildings, too? If not, what should define "inside" and "outside"? Does it have to be source water or can it be water flowing down?

Comment: Creative mode.  If chambers are properly sealed they shouldn't flood.  This is meant to test their building designs and demonstrate the challenge of building something like this.  So ideally, water from the surrounding ocean would flow in and fill the open areas of the chamber.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then this is very similar to something I already have on my todo list: A "cave outliner", that tells you which caves are connected, in which directions they go, allow you to execute commands in every position in the cave, etc. It could also do this flooding operation very easily… if it was already done. Because the problem is that this is a major programming project, there isn't just a simple solution to this. But I think I have a different method for you, one that makes water behave and look like not water. I'll write an answer in a few hours.

Comment: Oh wait, my solution doesn't work in 1.7.10, only 1.13. Is there any way you can update? What is holding you back from updating?

Comment: serge said earlier that they run MinecraftEdu, which never got an update past 1.7.10 and has since been replaced by MC:EE. if you were to want the update, the library would need to purchase and install MC:EE separately, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Making water fill an area the way you want (flowing into openings, but staying out of enclosed areas, etc.) is very difficult and would create a lot of lag when it gets applied. From your comments I figured out that just making the water first undetectable and then later detectable would solve your issue as well, you don't actually need the water to be gone at first. How do you make water undetectable? With a combination of a resource pack and a data pack.

This solution only works in Minecraft 1.13 and above. I don't know exactly why you are in 1.7.10, you have to figure out yourself whether you can upgrade. There's not really any way to do what I'm doing here in any way before 1.13.

---

First I created a resource pack with this layout:

```
assets
 minecraft
  sounds
   ambient
    underwater
     additions
      water1.ogg*
      water2.ogg*
     underwater_ambience.ogg*
   liquid
    water.ogg*
   music
    game
     water
      axolotl.ogg*
      dragon_fish.ogg*
      shuniji.ogg*
  textures
   block
    water_flow.png (a 32×32 completely transparent image)
    water_overlay.png (a 32×32 completely transparent image)
    water_still.png (a 32×32 completely transparent image)
   misc
    underwater.png (a 32×1024 completely transparent image)
pack.png (just a nice little image of a crossed out bucket)
pack.mcmeta with the content »{"pack":{"pack_format":4,"description":"Makes water undetectable, together with the data pack."}}«
```

*an empty sound file, downloadable [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1pVA4gNoJi3OElyYmNRbEROU0U)

I don't know if all of these are necessary, but it's always better to be safe.

Enabling this resource pack already does a lot for hiding water, but it still weakens light, makes the sky blue, reduces the view angle, lets you swim and so on. So there's additionally a data pack that removed these effects. To do that, it makes water not behave like water, by just overwriting the `water.json` tag with an empty list. This still changes the FOV inside water (due to the bug [MC-147936](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-147936)) but it can be balanced by giving the player a speed 1 effect whenever they are inside water. This is done with a function. This function also gives everyone night vision so that they don't see the shadow of water. Due to another bug, this speed effect doesn't actually speed up flying players, so it should be fine. If not, everyone has to set their FOV wider manually in the game settings.

Here is the layout of the data pack:

```
data
 minecraft
  functions
   fov.mcfunction with the contents »effect give @a night_vision 11 0 true«(new line)»execute as @a at @s anchored eyes if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:water run effect give @s speed 1 0 true«
  tags
   fluids
    water.json with the contents »{"replace":true,"values":[]}«
   functions
    tick.json with the contents »{"values":["minecraft:fov"]}«
pack.mcmeta with the content »{"pack":{"pack_format":3,"description":"Makes water undetectable, together with the resource pack."}}«
```

What still happens with these two packs is that blocks like torches are flooded away by the water, but that would happen as soon as you add the water later anyway. Also, mobs can spawn and other effects of low light levels can still happen below water, but since this is a Creative building server, that hopefully shouldn't be too much of an issue.

**How to apply**:
The resource pack has to be linked in the `server.properties` file under the `resource-pack` option of a server, if it's running there, see [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack#Default_resource_packs) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Resource_pack&oldid=1364202#Default_resource_packs)). Otherwise it just goes into the [usual resource pack location](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack#Behavior) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Resource_pack&oldid=1364202#Behavior)) and has to be enabled from the resource pack menu.
The data pack goes into the [usual data pack location](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_pack#Usage) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Data_pack&oldid=1364664#Usage)). Then enter `/datapack enable "file/disable_water_data_pack"` into the server console or into chat if you have command permissions. You might also have to do the same with `/reload`.
Here are zip files of the complete [resource pack](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-3I0QKDTIVqpKkXMFVeuEGyg4IoGsSSk) and [data pack](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zKgeVPTVuPenuwzLfRLZDMyp6btZ6GWT), both don't even have to be extracted, they already work as zip files.

Comment: I updated the datapack so that it now works without unpacking.

Comment: Subtitles of water sounds still show this way, I will correct the resource pack one day.

Comment: Actually, it seems like a lot of things are still not disabled with this: particles when entering and leaving water, general underwater particles, a bunch of sounds, a bunch of subtitles, … Not all of those are completely consistent either, for example a lot of subtitles are missing in Vanilla already. And the resource pack format has changed since I wrote this answer. So I will only update and complete if someone requests it. But I have at least updated the resource pack so that it actually works without unpacking.

Answer (score -2):

Either,

A) Install worldedit for 1.7.10

B) Do it manually. (Go into creative, get a water bucket and spam right click)

Comment: The bucket would work, but the kids wouldn't have the patience for it.  I'll look into Worldedit.  I've also been investigating Buildcraft's floodgates to this end.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to use worldedit, make sure to learn how to use it. Because sometimes people install worldedit on their servers and then they just mess the server up. https://youtu.be/SOOvommDpUA